# Can I repurpose a vehicle body to make a pull trailer?

Tags: jeep, trailer

I have a couple older vehicles in my yard and I'm wondering if I can repurpose them. I'd actually like to strip one down and make a pull trailer. Is that feasible?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: It would be interesting to know what kind of vehicles you're working with, and to think about how you want to use the trailer and whether the vehicle's height, weight, rear axle position are suitable, whether or not the tail lights could be reused or you need to install new ones.  Also whether the vehicles are currently titled or title-able to you and what your state or country's requirements are for registering a  home-made trailer for road use.

Answer (score 2):

It is absolutely feasible ... however (yes, don't these all come with a caveat?) ... there is a catch.

Can it be done? The answer is "yes it can". To do it, you have to have something which will work for your purpose. I've seen it done with the back half of a pickup truck. The frame is cut at the front of the bed, then a tongue is welded to the frame at the front to allow it to be towed. The axle stays in place along with the tires. You'd need to figure out wiring so you could attach it to your tow vehicle and have brake/turn lights which show what your intentions are while towing (just like any other trailer you'd see on the road). [Here's a video of how one guy did just this.](https://youtu.be/ljjOmq8xrGk)

Now for the caveat. It has to be legal where you live. In a lot of places, trailers need to be inspected on a regular basis in order to be used on the road. It might also need a license. Before you go throwing down on creating something like this, you need to know if it's legal in your area.

Comment: Thanks Paulster2, I'll check the link. Hopefully I'm allowed to proceed.

Comment: I appreciated the video, however I have an entire jeep. I suppose I could get a Sawzall after it after parting it out. ?? Get rid of fluids first and go from there?